How to configure the implementation under Ubuntu 22.04 cgroup v2 for restricting CPU usage for user accounts?
How to configure the implementation under Ubuntu 22.04 cgroup v2.
For example

A user (all processes and subsequent processes), limited to 100% CPU usage
B user (all processes and subsequent processes), limited to 200% CPU usage

I have successfully configured in the environment of CentOS 7 cgroup v1 (cgconfig.conf and cgrules.conf),
But how to do it in the Ubuntu 22.04 cgroup v2 environment?
